# Can't connect to Internet via D-Link Dir-600 Router on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.10 and have trouble accessing the internet with my current network setup at home. (Cisco EPC2308G Moden - D-Link DIR-600 Router - Samsung R540 Laptop)

- I can access the internet when i connect the Laptop directly to the modem via ethernet
- I could access the internet with Ubuntu without problems on other WLAN-Networks (at work)
- I cannot access the internet via ethernet when the router is pluged in between modem & laptop
- I cannot access the internet via WiFi. When I connect via wireless, I will sometimes be able to open one or two pages. After a few seconds I am not able to open new sites.
- Router works on Windows 7 partition.

This data might be of some use:

```
Beschreibung: Kabellose Verbindung
   Produkt: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
   Hersteller: Qualcomm Atheros
   Physische ID: 0
   Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:02:00.0
   Logischer Name: wlan0
   Version: 01
   Seriennummer: b4:74:9f:af:6e:fc
   Breite: 64 bits
   Takt: 33MHz
   Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   Konfiguration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.16.0-31-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.11 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   Ressourcen: irq:16 memory:fc500000-fc50ffff
*-network
   Beschreibung: Ethernet interface
   Produkt: 88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller
   Hersteller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
   Physische ID: 0
   Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:06:00.0
   Logischer Name: eth0
   Version: 00
   Seriennummer: e8:11:32:51:e8:16
   Größe: 100Mbit/s
   Kapazität: 100Mbit/s
   Breite: 64 bits
   Takt: 33MHz
   Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   Konfiguration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sky2 driverversion=1.30 duplex=full latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
   Ressourcen: irq:40 memory:fc600000-fc603fff ioport:4000(Größe=256)
```

Let me know, if there is any other usefull information I should provide.
Thank you in advance. 
Best regards.

Comment: Furteher information: 

I can access the internet via lan with the router using a strange "trick" which seems pretty odd. If i establish a connection to the internet, using the ethernet cable on the modem directly. After the connection is establiched, i can plug out the cable and conect the router to it, and the connection will be kept up. Funny thing is i can access the internet then, but not access the router by his ip 192.168.0.2

I furthermore found out that DHCP is disabled in the router settings.

Comment: I just changed the Router IP. That had some poitive effect as it seems. Wifi connection is up for quite some minutes now.

Comment: Did you enable DHCP on the router or are you using a static configuration with DNS set in network manager?

Comment: Not sure really... I think the info provided above by me was wrong. Wan is connected via DHCP Client. The info that  DHCP-Server is deactivated was refering to the LAN Setup. However, though not sure how the chance of the IP could have solved the problem, everything is working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since it will connect with wifi at work, I would look at your wifi router settings and see if the encryption is set for WPA2 only with no TKIP or WEP as it seems that Linux has issues when WEP or TKIP is used

Comment: Dear Jeremy. Thank you for your reply. Changeing the encryption on the router did not bring up results. I will be able access websites for a few minutes, then after a few minutes the connection drops and I won't be able to open new pages.